# How do I get the FSM table from the given diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, state-machines

Given one is question and another solution. I cant come to this solution. can anyone help here

[image: Given FSM moore machine]

[image: solution]

Comment: I think you should post what you have tired so far to solve this problem so that someone here can tell you how to proceed. Directly giving answer won't help you also.

Comment: The question (not yours) is pretty badly written and hard to understand right :-( - "a circuit consisting of an FSM and an adder"?! The FSM does not designate a start state, the signal descriptions do not match and are mixed in the following sentence.